# What's the different between with a ~ and without a ~ in a string variable in Bash?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, home, tilde

I'm using a dotfile manage software, named [dotdrop](https://github.com/deadc0de6/dotdrop). Using a config file named `.env`, contents like: `git_folder="~/code/Git"`.

Also use a script to setup this dotfile tool before the first use of it, as follows,

```
#!/bin/bash

env1="~/Dropbox/.env"
env2="/mnt/d/Dropbox/.env"

if [ -f $env1 ]; then
    echo "Found dotdrop env file, installing dotfiles..."
    source $env1
    eval $(grep -v "^#" $env1) dotdrop --cfg=${git_folder}/dotfiles/config.yaml install
elif [ -f $env2 ]; then
    echo "Found dotdrop env file, installing dotfiles..."
    source $env2
    eval $(grep -v "^#" $env2) dotdrop --cfg=${git_folder}/dotfiles/config.yaml install
else echo "Pls sync environment files first!"
fi
```

If I store my config file at `~/Dropbox/.env`, when I run the script, I just got `"Pls sync environment files first!"`(run in if condition is expected). If config file stored at `/mnt/d/Dropbox/.env`, the script will go through the elif condition, which is expected.

Find the reason until I run the script in dubug mode, and get the difference:

```
➜  scripts git:(master) ✗ bash -x dotdrop_setup.sh 
+ env1='~/Dropbox/.env'
+ env2=/mnt/d/Dropbox/.env
+ '[' -f '~/Dropbox/.env' ']'
+ '[' -f /mnt/d/Dropbox/.env ']'
+ echo 'Pls sync environment files first!'
Pls sync environment files first!
```

So, I think the difference between `~` and `/home/user` is the reason.

After I change `~` to `/home/roach`(roach is user name), it works.

```
➜  scripts git:(master) ✗ bash -x dotdrop_setup.sh
+ env1=/home/roach/Dropbox/.env
+ env2=/mnt/d/Dropbox/.env
+ '[' -f /home/roach/Dropbox/.env ']'
+ echo 'Found dotdrop env file, installing dotfiles...'
Found dotdrop env file, installing dotfiles...
+ source /home/roach/Dropbox/.env
++ git_folder='~/code/Git'
++ grep -v '^#' /home/roach/Dropbox/.env
+ eval git_folder='~/code/Git'
++ dotdrop '--cfg=~/code/Git/dotfiles/config.yaml' install
     _       _      _
  __| | ___ | |_ __| |_ __ ___  _ __
 / _` |/ _ \| __/ _` | '__/ _ \| '_ |
 \__,_|\___/ \__\__,_|_|  \___/| .__/  v0.22.0
                               |_|


0 dotfile(s) installed.
```

The debug shows `''` surround `+ env1='~/Dropbox/.env'` is removed which I think is the reason.

But, **WHY**?

---

Additional question,

`alias dotdrop="eval $(grep -v "^#" $env1) /usr/bin/dotdrop --cfg=${git_folder}/dotfiles/config.yaml install"` is a config add to `bashrc`, `zshrc`, etc. It doesn't work if I add it to my script directly!

Finally, found I have to add `source $env`,

So **WHY** it works in a bashrc file?

Comment: Are you running this script with some other user then `user` you mentioned in question?

Comment: Hi, @Debian_yadav. I run with same user not sure for your meaning, so I updated some detail about this question.

Comment: Hi, @JulienLopez. I think for this question the answer is `Tilde (~) not expand inside double quotes` not `WHY Tilde (~) not expand inside double quotes?`. Cause if I kown `Tilde (~) not expand inside double quotes` I will not ask this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`~` is a shortcut for your home directory, but only when it appears at the beginning of a string **outside quotes**. The beginning of the right-hand side of an assignment operator is the beginning of a string, so `env1=~/Dropbox/.env` would work (or `env1=~"/Dropbox/.env"` or any number of variations). It sets `env1` to `/home/roach/Dropbox/.env`. But `env1="~/Dropbox/.env"` sets `env1` to the exact string `~/Dropbox/.env`, which as a file name looks inside a directory with the one-character name `~` in the current directory.

Tilde is an abbreviation, not a wildcard. `$env1` outside quotes expands wildcards in the value of `env1`, but it doesn't expand the tilde because the tilde is not a wildcard.

You can also use `env1="$HOME/Dropbox/.env"`. This is equivalent to `env1=~/Dropbox/.env`. The character `$` (dollar) has a special meaning inside double quotes (it's the same meaning as outside quotes): it starts a variable substitution (or a command or arithmetic substitution). The character `~` (tilde), on the other hand, is just an ordinary character when it's inside quotes, even double quotes.

---

As for the alias, the reason it doesn't work in a bash script is that bash doesn't expand aliases in scripts by default. It won't work in any script unless you include or source the definition of the alias in that script, since aliases are a property of each shell instance. They aren't part of a process's environment.

The reason the alias works at all in your second script is that dotdrop itself expands the tilde when it reads its configuration value.

Comment: Also note, that in the assignment `env1=~'/Dropbox/.env`, the tilda replacement is performed before the statement execution (which is the assignment in this case), so in fact the variable `env1` is really not assigned the tilda sign this way. If you want the tilda to be part of the value and expanded lateron, then leave it within the quotes and struggle with `eval`.